# Android: Trying to draw multiple paths, but getting one long path instead

Tags: android, path, drawing, android-canvas

No doubt I'm doing something dumb, but I can't seem to spot it.  I am trying to draw paths based on the users touch.  The code to capture those individual touches is:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // The user is starting a new path
            Path path = new Path();
            paths.push(path);
            path.moveTo(x,y);
            path.lineTo(x,y);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // The user is drawing on the current path
            path = paths.getLast();
            path.quadTo(x,y, (lastX + x)/2f, (lastY + y)/2f);
            break;
    }

    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

And then to draw the lines:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    ListIterator<Path> iterator = paths.listIterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Path path = iterator.next();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I start to draw a second (or nth) path, the code is adding a line between the endpoint of the last and the beginning of the current one.  Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had created a DrawCanvas application. you can download it [here](https://github.com/prijupaul/Priju/tree/master/DrawCanvas) and check how it works.